# If i run dotnet proj in docker container "This page isn’t working right now"

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core

I tried to run my multiply dotnet project in a docker container but it didn't not work. I got a message in my browser <<This page isn’t working right now localhost didn’t send any data.>>
Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Core/Core.csproj", "Core/"]

RUN dotnet restore "./API/./API.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "./API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/API.dll"]
```

Program.cs
`app.Run("http://localhost:5000");`

in console i run
docker build -t app .
docker run -it -p 5000:80 docker

I tried to use another ports. But it didn't help. I used to used wsl. Then I tried to use it in linux, but it also didn't help.
I read forums to solve this problem.

Comment: Try changing `app.Run("http://localhost:5000");` to `app.Run();`

Answer (score 1):

In program.cs

```
app.Run();
```

In dockerfile,expose port at base and set port at entrypoint.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Core/Core.csproj", "Core/"]

RUN dotnet restore "./API/./API.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "./API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false



FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/API.dll","--server.urls","http://*/5000"]
```

Comment: Thank you. Then i just run it with -p 5000:5000